# How do I check if all the elements in a 2D array are equal in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a simple array that contains a minimum of 2, max of 10 strings. The string entries are fixed (WI, CT, CTRW, GF). I need to compare the contents of this array to find out if they are all equal. What I have works, ONLY IF the array is 2 - 3 elements in size. If it contains 4 or more elements, it returns TRUE regardless even if that is not the case. I haven't figured out how to fix this. I understand why it doesn't work, but don't know how to get around the issue. Any suggestions?  (Code Below)

```
for (int i = 1; i < numLogs; i++)
{           
  if(logType[i-1] == logType[i])
  {
   return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a little bit of Linq:

```
return logType.Cast<string>().Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

- [`Cast<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) converts the `string[,]` array to an `IEnumerable<string>` so you can use the conventional Linq extension methods.
- [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets the set of distinct elements in the list.
- [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of items in the previous set.

And here's a more efficient, but slightly less easy to read solution:

```
return !logType.Cast<string>().Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
```

- `Cast<string>` converts the `string[,]` array to an `IEnumerable<string>`
- `Distinct` gets the set of distinct elements in the list.
- [`Skip(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ignores the first item from the previous set.
- [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `true` if there are any items in the previous set (after the one that was skipped)
- Finally, the result is negated with `!`. Note that this means the method will return true if the input array is empty.

The second solution is more efficient, because is allows the result to be returned immediately when a second string is found in the set, whereas the first must continue counting until all distinct items are found.

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. Need to do more homework on LinQ now.

Comment: @Matchrocket I'm glad I could help. If this answer has resolved your issue, you should consider accepting it. This indicates to other users that the problem has been solved, and it helps other visitors who may have the same issue know that this answer may help them as well. Once you earn enough reputation you can also upvote any answer you found helpful. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).